# Birkhoff ergodic Theorem proof: why is this set measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I'm trying to understand the first claim in the proof of the Birkhoff ergodic theorem.

The setup is:

- $T$ is measure-preserving on a $\sigma$-finite measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$,
- $f: \Omega \to \mathbf{R}^*$ is a measurable function, and
- $r<s$ are rational.

Why is the set of points $x$ such that $$\liminf \left[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(T^i(x))\right] < r < s < \limsup \left[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(T^i(x))\right]$$ measurable?

Comment: For any two measurable functions $f$ and $g$ the set $$\{x; f(x)<r<s<g(x)\}$$ is measurable, right? So where exactly is your problem?

Comment: I see now. I was intimidated by the functions on the left and right hand sides. Didn't realize they were both clearly measurable. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome.